# CompileError when trying to run Insert Statement on SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

The script I'm writing requests news article metadata from an API. In response, it receives a page of results containing several news articles. It is designed to process the records one at a time, extracting the data fields from the json dict and inserting them into postgres.

However, when I run the insert operation, the function returns:

```
CompileError: Unconsumed column names: urlToImage, publishedAt
```

How do I get this insert operation to work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData # for getting table metadata
from sqlalchemy import Table # for interacting with tables
from sqlalchemy import create_engine # for creating db engine 
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert # for getting alterate query method to work

# Create DB engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{hostip}/{db}'.format(**dbkeys))


# Get metadata objects for tables in database
metadata = MetaData(engine, reflect=True)
nstream = metadata.tables['nstream']    


for item in response_page['articles']:
    # Convert datetime strings from api into Python datetime format
    dtp = datetime.strptime(item['publishedAt'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

    inserttw = nstream.insert().values(source_id = item['source']['id'], 
                                      source_name = item['source']['name'], 
                                      author = item['author'],
                                      title = item['title'],
                                      description = item['description'],
                                      url = item['url'],
                                      urlToImage = item['urlToImage'],
                                      publishedAt = dtp,
                                      uploaded2db = datetime.now(),
                                      content = item['content'])
    engine.execute(inserttw)
```

And the full traceback:

```
CompileError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-c5f4a6bff45e> in <module>
     63     # 2. If query has more than one page, get additional pages
     64 
---> 65 get_results(tfrom, engine = engine, max_retries = 5)

<ipython-input-10-c5f4a6bff45e> in get_results(tfrom, engine, max_retries)
     39 
     40             # Append the results to the database using the helper
---> 41             process_page(results)
     42 
     43         # If there is an exception, add to the retry counter and then sleep.

<ipython-input-10-c5f4a6bff45e> in process_page(response_page)
     26                                           uploaded2db = datetime.now(),
     27                                           content = item['content'])
---> 28         engine.execute(inserttw)
     29 
     30 def get_results(tfrom, engine = engine, max_retries = 5):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params)
   2073 
   2074         connection = self.contextual_connect(close_with_result=True)
-> 2075         return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
   2076 
   2077     def scalar(self, statement, *multiparams, **params):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in execute(self, object, *multiparams, **params)
    946             raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(object)
    947         else:
--> 948             return meth(self, multiparams, params)
    949 
    950     def _execute_function(self, func, multiparams, params):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py in _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params)
    267     def _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params):
    268         if self.supports_execution:
--> 269             return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
    270         else:
    271             raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_clauseelement(self, elem, multiparams, params)
   1051                 inline=len(distilled_params) > 1,
   1052                 schema_translate_map=self.schema_for_object
-> 1053                 if not self.schema_for_object.is_default else None)
   1054 
   1055         ret = self._execute_context(

<string> in <lambda>(self, bind, dialect, **kw)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py in compile(self, default, bind, dialect, **kw)
    440             else:
    441                 dialect = default.StrCompileDialect()
--> 442         return self._compiler(dialect, bind=bind, **kw)
    443 
    444     def _compiler(self, dialect, **kw):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py in _compiler(self, dialect, **kw)
    446         Dialect."""
    447 
--> 448         return dialect.statement_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)
    449 
    450     def __str__(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py in __init__(self, dialect, statement, column_keys, inline, **kwargs)
    451         # dialect.label_length or dialect.max_identifier_length
    452         self.truncated_names = {}
--> 453         Compiled.__init__(self, dialect, statement, **kwargs)
    454 
    455         if (

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py in __init__(self, dialect, statement, bind, schema_translate_map, compile_kwargs)
    217             if self.can_execute:
    218                 self.execution_options = statement._execution_options
--> 219             self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)
    220 
    221     @util.deprecated("0.7", ":class:`.Compiled` objects now compile "

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py in process(self, obj, **kwargs)
    243 
    244     def process(self, obj, **kwargs):
--> 245         return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
    246 
    247     def __str__(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py in _compiler_dispatch(self, visitor, **kw)
     79                     raise exc.UnsupportedCompilationError(visitor, cls)
     80                 else:
---> 81                     return meth(self, **kw)
     82         else:
     83             # The optimization opportunity is lost for this case because the

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py in visit_insert(self, insert_stmt, asfrom, **kw)
   2057 
   2058         crud_params = crud._setup_crud_params(
-> 2059             self, insert_stmt, crud.ISINSERT, **kw)
   2060 
   2061         if not crud_params and \

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/crud.py in _setup_crud_params(compiler, stmt, local_stmt_type, **kw)
     55     try:
     56         if local_stmt_type in (ISINSERT, ISUPDATE):
---> 57             return _get_crud_params(compiler, stmt, **kw)
     58     finally:
     59         if should_restore:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/crud.py in _get_crud_params(compiler, stmt, **kw)
    144             raise exc.CompileError(
    145                 "Unconsumed column names: %s" %
--> 146                 (", ".join("%s" % c for c in check))
    147             )
    148 

CompileError: Unconsumed column names: urlToImage, publishedAt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem, as it turned out was that I was capitalizing the column names wrong.

I figured this out by using [SQLalchemy's inspector function](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html#fine-grained-reflection-with-inspector). The column names were there, they were just in lower case.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import reflection
insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
print(insp.get_columns(nstream))
```

The source of the confusion is that when you create tables in Postgres, Postgres will automatically [lower case your column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive) unless you use quotes when naming them.

This is the working version of the insert command:

```
inserttw = nstream.insert().values(source_id = item['source']['id'], 
                                  source_name = item['source']['name'], 
                                  author = item['author'],
                                  title = item['title'],
                                  description = item['description'],
                                  url = item['url'],
                                  urltoimage = item['urlToImage'],
                                  publishedat = dtp,
                                  uploaded2db = datetime.now(),
                                  content = item['content'])
```