# Writing to postgres using Apache beam with beam-nuggets error: CompileError: Unconsumed column names

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, apache-beam

I am getting this error when I try 2 relational_db.Write from the same Pcollection.

Its very strange that sometimes it works, sometimes doesnt.

From persons_raw to persons_stage I added 3 new columns to the dict: tra_personalEmail, tra_companyDomain, tra_linkedInProfile

I tried to change the order, but didn't work.

Does anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance

Code:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

persons_raw = (
p
|'Create pipeline' >> beam.Create(['data.csv'])
|'Read multiline CSV' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda filename: csv.reader(io.TextIOWrapper(beam.io.filesystems.FileSystems.open(input_path),encoding='utf-8')))
|'Remove header' >> beam.Filter(lambda x: x[0] != 'FIRST NAME')
|'Raw schema' >> beam.Map(schema_persons_raw)
)

persons_raw_to_postgres = (
persons_raw
|'Persons_raw to DB' >> relational_db.Write(source_config=source_config,table_config=table_config_persons_raw)
)

persons_stage = (
persons_raw
|'Personal E-mail' >> beam.Map(tra_personal_email)
|'Company domain' >> beam.Map(tra_company_domain)
|'Linkedin url' >> beam.Map(tra_linkedin_url)
)

persons_stage_to_postgres = (
persons_stage
|'Persons_stage to DB' >> relational_db.Write(source_config=source_config,table_config=table_config_persons_stage)
)
```

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Unconsumed column names: tra_personalEmail, tra_companyDomain, tra_linkedInProfile [while running 'Persons_raw to DB/ParDo(_WriteToRelationalDBFn)']
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar question [CompileError when trying to run Insert Statement on SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54116663/compileerror-when-trying-to-run-insert-statement-on-sqlalchemy).

> The source of the confusion is that when you create tables in Postgres, Postgres will automatically lower case your column names unless you use quotes when naming them.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. but I think that's not the case because when I comment one of the write db transforms, the other one works. Also, sometimes both works in the same run